# getClass().getResourceAsStream does not read the whole file

Tags: java, jar

I am running a Java jar program which contains a file. The program starts reading from the file and then crashes.

```
InputStream stream=Swgh.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/dat.uvptw");
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(stream,"UTF-8");
```

But when I run it from Eclipse using `new file("dat.uvptw")` it doesn't crash and reads all the file.

```
Scanner scanner=new Scanner(new File("dat.uvptw"),"UTF-8");
```

Comment: maybe a problem of memory !!

Comment: when it crashes, is there a stack trace/error message? if so, please provide the same.

Comment: it crashes on scanner.nextint. and the error is
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
keep in mind that the code is working when i use the second code.